# VB.Net how change opacity to image or bitmap?

Tags: vb.net, graphics, drawing

I have a sub in VB.Net to perform a opacity of a image, but, doesn't work like I expect:

```
Public Sub mc_SetOpacity(ByRef Image As Image, ByVal Opacity As Double)
        Dim vGraphics As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Image)
        Dim vColorMatrix As New ColorMatrix()
        Dim vImgAtt As New ImageAttributes()

        vColorMatrix.Matrix33 = Opacity

        vImgAtt.SetColorMatrix(vColorMatrix, ColorMatrixFlag.[Default], ColorAdjustType.Bitmap)
        vGraphics.DrawImage(Image, New Rectangle(0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height), 0, 0, Image.Width, Image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, vImgAtt)

        vGraphics.Dispose() : vGraphics = Nothing
        vImgAtt.Dispose() : vImgAtt = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Somebody can tell me what I doing wrong?

Comment: @Brad: Make the image of the parameter more transparent

Comment: Changing the Opacity of a Bitmap image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779027/changing-the-opacity-of-a-bitmap-image