# Second timer.Start() isn't being triggered by first timer tick

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

So I have a small logo in the lower right corner of a Form that I want to fade in and out at a preset speed, about 6 seconds per fade. I have tried a few different methods but I can never get the picture to fade back in again once the first timer has finished. Here's my code for the the 2 timers and their respective tick methods.

EDIT The declarations for the timers included now.

```
        Timer fade = new Timer();
        Timer fade2 = new Timer();


                fade.Interval = (200);
                fade.Tick += new EventHandler(fade_Tick);


                fade2.Interval = (200);
                fade2.Tick += new EventHandler(fade_Tick_Two);

                fade.Start();

private void fade_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (alpha < 255)
            {
                image = picboxPic.Image;
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                {
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(alpha, 255, 255, 255), image.Width);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, -1, -1, image.Width, image.Height);
                    g.Save();
                }
                picboxPic.Image = image;
                this.Invalidate();
                alpha++;
            }
            else
            {
                fade.Stop();
                fade2.Start();
            }


        }
private void fade_Tick_Two(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (alpha > 0)
            {
                image = picboxPic.Image;
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
                {
                    Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(alpha, 255, 255, 255), image.Width);
                    g.DrawLine(pen, -1, -1, image.Width, image.Height);
                    g.Save();
                }
                picboxPic.Image = image;
                this.Invalidate();
                alpha--;
            }
            else
            {
                fade2.Stop();
                fade.Start();
            }

        }
```

Any ideas as to why the second timer won't start? I've used breakpoints and the alpha level does reach 255 but then it doesn't trigger the second Tick event.

Comment: Can you include the declarations for fade and fade2?

Comment: Edited @Marisa :)

Comment: I've copied your code into a new project form, commented out all the image manipulations and run it: it perfectly hits fade_Tick_Two after alpha value reaches 255.

Comment: It works just fine, the real issue is that there is nothing left of the original image anymore.   A fade from white to white is not observable.  Don't lose the original.

Comment: I have the original as an imbedded resource for the solution @HansPassant but now that I know that the timer is in fact triggering then it shouldnt take too long to work out the image issue.

Comment: In which case you need to reload it in the picture box.

Comment: Acually, you are painting the imageout so once it fades there isn't anything left! [Try just changing the alpha by reading this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779027/changing-the-opacity-of-a-bitmap-image)

Comment: That method doesn't work @KevinFord its what I orginally used but then changed it to the above method after trialing it.

Comment: Ah! My comment was in response to a quick look, I will look further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method described in the link I quoted works for me:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        test();
    }
    System.Timers.Timer fade = new System.Timers.Timer(50);
    System.Timers.Timer fade2 = new System.Timers.Timer(50);
    Image originalImage = Image.FromFile(@"D:\kevin\Pictures\odds&Sods\kitchener.jpg");

    int alpha = 100;

    void test()
    {
        fade.Elapsed +=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fade_Tick);
        fade2.Elapsed+=new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(fade_Tick_Two);
        fade.Start();

    }
    delegate void timerDelegate(object sender, EventArgs e);
    private void fade_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new timerDelegate(fade_Tick), sender, e);
            return;
        }
        if (alpha >= 0)
        {
            picboxPic.Image =  SetImgOpacity(originalImage, alphaToOpacity(alpha));
            picboxPic.Invalidate();
            alpha--;
        }
        if (alpha < 0)
        {
            alpha = 0;
            fade.Stop();
            fade2.Start();
        }
    }
    private void fade_Tick_Two(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new timerDelegate(fade_Tick_Two), sender, e);
            return;
        }
        if (alpha <= 100)
        {
            picboxPic.Image = SetImgOpacity(originalImage, alphaToOpacity(alpha));
            picboxPic.Invalidate();
            alpha++;
        }
        if (alpha > 100)
        {
            alpha = 100;
            fade2.Stop();
            fade.Start();
        }
    }

    float alphaToOpacity(int alpha)
    {
        if (alpha == 0)
            return 0.0f;

        return (float)alpha / 100.0f;
    }

    //Setting the opacity of the image
    public static Image SetImgOpacity(Image imgPic, float imgOpac)
    {
        Bitmap bmpPic = new Bitmap(imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height);
        Graphics gfxPic = Graphics.FromImage(bmpPic);

        ColorMatrix cmxPic = new ColorMatrix();
        cmxPic.Matrix33 = imgOpac;
        ImageAttributes iaPic = new ImageAttributes();
        iaPic.SetColorMatrix(cmxPic, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
        gfxPic.DrawImage(imgPic, new Rectangle(0, 0, bmpPic.Width, bmpPic.Height), 0, 0, imgPic.Width, imgPic.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, iaPic);
        gfxPic.Dispose();

        return bmpPic;
    }
}
```

The code is a bit crude and you will need to take care of the dispose when you close the form, but it fades up and and down and the rest can easily be taken care of - I also made it quicker for testing 'cos life's short :-)

Comment: You are most welcome, though it isn't even my solution! So thanks go to @Venkatesh Appala and [@
RaviRanjanKr over at Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/201129/Change-Opacity-of-Image-in-C)

Comment: [You might want to give the reference answer an upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779027/changing-the-opacity-of-a-bitmap-image) - I have done so already.